# Mongo database how to use email as unique key?

Tags: mongodb, unique-key

I creted a mongodb collection and wanted to mark "email" field as unique in it, so I did this (it's a Java code though language isn't actually important here):

```
IndexOptions indexOptions = new IndexOptions();
indexOptions.unique(true);
userCollection.createIndex(Indexes.text("email"), indexOptions);
```

Then I try to insert 2 documents like so:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.append("email", "johnny@gmail.com");
doc.append("username", "John");
doc.append("lastname", "Doe");
userCollection.insertOne(document);

Document doc = new Document();
doc.append("email", "duck@gmail.com");
doc.append("username", "Donald");
doc.append("lastname", "Duck");
userCollection.insertOne(document);
```

The first one inserts without any problems, the second one throws this exception:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: wagon.w_users index:
>   email_text dup key: { : "com", : 0.6666666666666666 }

If I change gmail.com to e.g. gmail.comm, it throws this exception

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: wagon.w_users index: email_text
>   dup key: { : "gmail", : 0.6666666666666666 }

The workaround I see is to hash user's email and create a field like "emailhash" but it looks like a crutch to me. Maybe I'm missing some important setting here? Can we use email as unique key at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error come from your index creation : you're creating a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) by using

```
userCollection.createIndex(Indexes.text("email"), indexOptions);
```

So mongodb parse your string around '@' and '.', and indexes extracted words. As your index is annotated with 'unique' option, your second insert fails.
Instead of that, create a simple ascending index :

```
userCollection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("email"), indexOptions);
```